# Trying to install fonts to Font Book (Mac) using the Terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, font-book

I've been trying to add "official company Fonts" to my DeployStudio workflow imaging new Macs. I'm testing it with Terminal and in the DeployStudio Runtime environment (like WinPE for PC).

Here’s the actual command:

```
find /Common/Fonts/ -type f -exec cp {} /System/Library/Fonts \;
```

The many fonts are in a folder structure that has many levels, hence the find command…

Each time I get a permission error using local admin or **root** user.

What am I missing? It's right in my face, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/System/Library/Fonts` is restricted with System Integrity Protection, since this folder is intended purely for macOS built-in first-party fonts.

Instead, choose one of the following locations depending on your intentions:

- `/Library/Fonts` to apply to every user, existing and newly created.
- `~/Library/Fonts` to apply to the current user.
- `/Library/User Template/Non_localized/Library/Fonts` to apply to new users.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for all the quick answers!

Looks like a simpler script did the trick:

```
cp -R /Volume/HDD/Fonts/ /Volume/HDD/Library/Fonts/
```

Have a good one!